# Rails 5.1, models and db relation, share datas with groups of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-keys, relational-database, ruby-on-rails-5

sorry for the title I didn't really know what to put in there to be really clear. So I'll be clear in my explanation.

Users can create Groups and Links via form. The users can join Groups via Member where member has `group_id` and `user_id` in the table. I would like to be able to share the Users Link within the group.
So when a user creates a group, other users join this group. And for now when a user creates a link, it's only for himself but I want the user to be able to share (or not) the links he created with the groups he is part of. If the user is a member of several groups then the user can choose in which group he wants to share the link he created.

I have 4 models : `Link.rb`, `User.rb`, `Member.rb` and `Group.rb`. Here are my relations :

```
#Link.rb:

    class Link < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :user
    end  

#User.rb :

    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :groups, :through => :members
    end  

#Member.rb :

    class Member < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :group

      validates :user_id, :presence => true
      validates :group_id, :presence => true
      validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:user_id, :group_id]}
    end

#Group.rb :

    class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_token :auth_token

        has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
        has_many :users, through: :members, source: :user
        belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"


        def to_param
            auth_token
        end

    end
```

What I tried :
I added a reference of `group_id` in the link table. And added `belong_to :group` in `link.rb`, and `has_many :links, dependent: :destroy` in `group.rb`.

In my new link form I added the current_user group_id in a select (to retrieve only the groups where the user is in) and on create the link is created with the group_id and the current_user id. That works.
Problem is that I have to enter a group_id which means I give no choice to the user and he has to give a group_id so basically he must share the link to the group. Which is not what I want.

What I thought about :
Maybe I should just go for the same idea as I did for members. Which means having a new table like `grouplinks` where I give the group_id, link_id and the user_id with relations in place so I can use the grouplink.id to share in my group or not. Is this a good option ? If yes what are the relations I should put in place ? Any other suggestion, maybe I'm completly wrong and there is something easy to do and I don't see it.

I will try to give a shot with some code I thought about :

```
#Link.rb:

    class Link < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :grouplink
    end  

#User.rb :

    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :grouplinks, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :groups, :through => :members
    end  

#Grouplink.rb :

    class Member < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :group
      belongs_to :link
    end

#Group.rb :

    class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_token :auth_token

        has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
        has_many :users, through: :members, source: :user
        belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
        has_many :groupslinks, :dependent => :destroy
        has_many :links, through: :grouplinks


        def to_param
            auth_token
        end

    end
```

Could that work out ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to create a join table with group_id and link_id. Since the Group Admin is the user who created the group, you don't even need to add user_id(member_id I suppose) since every member of that group can access the link. Get the user groups and add that link to that particular group and check the association.

`class GroupLink
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :link`

You can just do

`@group = @user.groups.find(params[:group_id])
 @group_link = @group.group_links.build(link_id: link_id)
 @group_link.save`

Let me know if you need anything else or clarify this.

Comment: I'm testing like I wrote in the second code. I did like you said, create a join table called grouplink where I have user_id (maybe not necessary yes), group_id and link_id. Now I'm on the show of the group, how can I retrieve the link.title instead of the ID. I can't go for `Group.find(1).links`. I can go for `Grouplink.find(1).group.name`, `Grouplink.find(1).user.name`, `Grouplink.find(1).link.title`. But via the group I don't think I can. I don't really want to loop through the grouplink since it doesnt make any sense really... I would rather loop the groups, any hint ?

Comment: Thanks that's pretty clear to create or share the link I should say. If I'm in the show view of the group. Can I somehow retrieve the link name and the URL ? Because like this I can just get the ID

Comment: I'm a idiot... `@group.grouplinks.all` and I loop through `.link.title` there we go...Thanks for your help tho !